# How do I initialize a subclass of UINavigationController programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm reading a book that is teaching me to implement "GameCenter", but there's a problem. I'm not using a storyboard in it, while the tutorial does. It says to go to the identity inspector of a navigation controller in storyboard and put in a custom class. I am wondering how to do this programmatically without using a storyboard.

The closest thing I know what to do is this, but I'm pretty sure it's wrong:

Code:

```
NavigationController *navigationController = [[NavigationController alloc] init];
```

Comment: It's absolutely correct. You seem to have a massive gap of information. Go to iTunes U and do an iOS course, you'll be grateful that you did.

Comment: @Guy Okay thanks, but I'm just looking for a solution now. So this sets it up? Is the `*navigationController` the name of the custom class?

Comment: Is your custom class a subclass of `UIViewController`, `UINavigationController`, `NSObject` or something else? What exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: @PanayotPanayotov I made the class a subclass of `UINavigationController`

Comment: `NavigationController` is the name of your class `*navigationController` is the name of the pointer to your created object. `[NavigationController alloc]` allocates the space for the created object `init` is the object's initialization method. In your NavigationController subclass's header, you have @interface <YourClassName> : <TheClassYouAreSubclassing>. Not to be rude, but you really need to understand these basics, not just get a solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

In your `AppDelegate.m` find this method

```
    -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options
    {
// create your custom class and assign a rootViewController. In your case your existing root controller
      NavigationController *navigationController = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.window.rootViewController];

//Change your existing rootViewController to your custom one
      [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];


      return YES;
    }
```

And you're all done!

Answer (score 0):

you need to #import the .h of your subclass of `UINavigationController` into whatever file you are working in, eg

```
#import "CustomNavController.h"
```

then if you want to create and instance of your custom nav controller you would go

```
CustomNavController *navigationController = [[CustomNavController alloc] init];
```

im not sure what you are trying to do with it though so hopefully thats all you need to know.